# Issue with file path when building for iOS Unity

Tags: c#, ios, json, unity-game-engine, path

I have a bunch of JSON files in my project which I'm using to load levels. However, I'm not sure where to find the path for them. They're located in Assets/Resources/LevelsData in my project.

I've tried `Application.dataPath + "Assets/Resources/LevelsData/"`, however that doesn't seem to appear. Can anyone tell me where it could be found using Application.dataPath? Like, after calling Application.dataPath, what do I add to get to the assets folder? Or does the project's file tree change when I run it on iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** use `Application.dataPath + "/Assets/Resources/LevelsData/` ***if the files are placed in the Resources folder***. This is because Unity encodes the files into binary form and renames them too. Files in the Resources folder must be read with `Resources.Load`.

You need `Resources.Load` and `TextAsset`.

Supported `TextAsset` formats:

*.txt
.html
.htm
.xml
.bytes
.json
.csv
.yaml
.fnt*

Now, let's read one your json files named `JsnFile1.json` located in `Assets/Resources/LevelsData/`.

```
void Start()
{
    string jsonFileDir = "LevelsData/JsnFile1";
    TextAsset jsonFile = Resources.Load(jsonFileDir, typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset;
    Debug.Log(jsonFile.text);
}
```

Notice that you don't put the extension of the file in `Resources.Load` function. If you do that, it will fail.

Let's load a GameObject prefab called Bullet in `Assets/Resources/LevelsData/`.

```
void Start()
{
    string objDirFileDir = "LevelsData/Bullet";
    GameObject jsonFile = Resources.Load(objDirFileDir, typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;
    Debug.Log(jsonFile.name);
}
```

Comment: The Resources folder is one I created. Does your solution depend on where the respective files are located? If that is the case, I'd much rather place them somewhere else and use my current form of loading.

Comment: Update: tried moving said files to another folder, didn't work

Comment: @MihaiStan No and no. Your files must be in the `Assets/Resources/LevelsData` directory to work. I never said you should move them. Put them back to where they were in your question and simply replace `JsnFile1` with the name of one of your files. Do not put the extension name. This has been tested before posting and should work. They all should be be placed at `Assets/Resources/LevelsData`

Comment: Should that work in the editor too? Because it doesn't

Comment: Ok. I tested it and it works again. Glad you got it working. What were you doing wrong?

Comment: Something about the Monobehaviour lifecycle set the path wrong. Long story short, I tried tinkering with my code instead of starting over with your solution.

Comment: Ok. I was pulling my hair here because it was just a simple solution. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

[Application.DataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html) gives you "/Assets" so you have to use

```
Application.dataPath + "/Resources/LevelsData/"
```

---

**EDIT**

for IOS it says this on documentation page:

> iOS player: //Data (this
>   folder is read only, use Application.persistentDataPath to save data).

Comment: Doesn't work. Apparently, it only gives you "/Assets" in the editor.

Comment: check the doc page that I linked in answer.

Comment: I had already read it, but it's not clear for me. Thank you nonetheless